# What determines which architecture an a.out executable runs on?

Tags: unix, file-format

The ELF file format has an `e_machine` field in the header, which specifies which ISA the executable expects. And the `e_ident` structure also has an `EI_OSABI` field that specifies which ABI the executable is expecting. My guess is, that these fields are how my operating system knows not to go ahead and run a binary which was compiled for some other machine.

But how was this achieved on early UNIXes, early Linuxes, and others that used `a.out`? `a.out`, from what I can tell, has no equivalent field(s).

Comment: It's not possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `a_midmag` field contains a machine identifier, which can be used on platforms which support that field. `a_midmag` is a 32-bit value stored in host byte-order (fun already), and bits 16 to 23 give the machine type. The most comprehensive list of machine identifiers I’ve found so far is [the list used by `libbfd`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=bfd/libaout.h;h=0a421e40e918050af44cc5673ccda53000df566f;hb=HEAD#l248), which shows that the field has been used for quite a long time (values 1, 2 and 3 indicate 68010, 68020 and SPARC respectively). [`file`](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/) also has a number of magic values, *e.g.* for [Sun systems](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/sun) and [the PDP-11](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/pdp).

Unfortunately the “platforms which support that field” caveat means that it can’t be relied upon, and [the FreeBSD `a.out` manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=a.out&sektion=5) highlights that fact:

> Since not all of the supported architectures use the `a_midmag` field, it
>        can be difficult to determine what architecture a binary will execute on
>        without examining its actual machine code.  Even with a machine identifier, the byte order of the `exec` header is machine-dependent.

Historically, `a.out` binaries were directly executable, their first bytes were a jump instruction to skip the header (see [the original documentation](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/man51.pdf)). So you *could* try to recognise old binaries’ architecture by figuring out whether the first (two?) bytes are a valid jump instruction with a sensible offset... Later binaries are not directly executable by the CPU; for example the start of a Linux `a.out` binary is [a magic number](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/linux) such as 0x0064010b (see for example [this old i386 `bash` binary](http://oldlinux.org/Linux.old/bin/bash-1.14.2.linux.bin.tar.gz)), which isn’t useful x86.

So the answer to your question is really that to determine what architecture an `a.out` executable runs on, you need to try to run it...

Answer (score 16):

The short answer is: early Unix systems did not bother to track which architecture an executable was for.  In general, the architecture an executable was for, was the one the executable was found on.

If you're on a PDP-11, /bin will contain PDP-11 executables.  If you're on a VAX, /bin will contain VAX executables.  Multiple architectures all trying to store their executables in the same file system was simply not a problem people were typically having, and therefore not a problem that needed fixing.

If you tried to run something for another architecture (e.g. you restored some files from a tape written on another system) the worst that would happen is the program would crash and give you a core dump.  If you were doing that kind of thing you were expected to know to either get the correct tape for your architecture, or recompile the software from source.

In those rare cases where you needed to have binaries from multiple architectures co-existing (e.g. a file server storing files) the early solutions were to do things like having separate directories for each architecture, e.g. /nfs/vax/bin, /nfs/sun3/bin, /nfs/ibm_rt/bin.  Then each client would be configured to use the particular directory that was appropriate.  Only a fool would mix executables for different architectures in the same directory (absent some other way to track them, e.g. architecture-specific suffixes).

Comment: I don't remember multi-architecture executables until Apple introduced "universal binaries" during one of their CPU changes on Macs. Did Unix do it earlier?

Comment: @Barmar Theoretically, it was possible to construct an executable that would work on both VAX and PDP-11, see [the first winner of the IOCCC](http://ioccc.org/1984/mullender/) - hint.html for the description.

Comment: @Barmar there were hacks on various systems where code could be written to load on multiple architectures, or OSs (DOS and CP/M for example). I think the first “specified” fat binary support was in NeXTSTEP.

Comment: There was a time when Sun Microsystems would sell you a Sun-3 (68010) network server, and a bunch of Sun-4 (SPARC) diskless clients. So the server had a full version of the OS installed for each machine type. Being a SysAdmin in that environment was fraught with problems involving PATH.

Answer (score 3):

There is no 100% sure way. For an earnest albeit somewhat futile attempt to recognize `a.out` files, see `/usr/share/magic` (on Linux; elsewhere your paths may vary) - the pattern file of the UNIX `file` command.

There you can see that both "386 executable" and "VAX executable" have the same magic header (0407) and the same offset for the symbol table length, and there is no other way to tell them apart except by execution. The first matching pattern ("386 executable", as in the file) will win, just because it is deemed more probable to encounter a 386 `a.out` executable than a VAX one.

Answer (score 2):

The `a.out` format is, in general, simply plain binary code. It contains no information whatsoever what platform it is intended for.

Obviously, any `a.out` binary will do *something* on any platform (the CPU, after all, simply interprets the binary code in the file according to its make and type), but the *intended* execution can only be achieved on the platform the a.out was built for.